# Recursive Function returns null value

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion, return

Below recursive function i am trying to get array of codes. For example input 'bme4', output should be like [0]=>'bme'[1]=>'bm'[2]=>'b'. But the return value is null eventhough i can get the correct return value with var_dump().

```
function get_parent_cat_code($code, $category_codes) {
    $parent_cat_code = substr($code, 0, -1);
    if ($parent_cat_code != ''){
        $category_codes[] = $parent_cat_code;
        get_parent_cat_code($parent_cat_code, $category_codes);
    } else {
        var_dump($category_codes);
        return $category_codes;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a reference in function header: `function get_parent_cat_code($code, &$category_codes){}`. Hint: use [PSR-1](https://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/) styleguide for better readable code.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Don't you know what a reference is? Look at the code I've put into the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

```
function get_parent_cat_code($code,$category_codes){
    $parent_cat_code=substr($code, 0, -1);
    if($parent_cat_code!=''){
        $category_codes[]=$parent_cat_code;
        return get_parent_cat_code($parent_cat_code,$category_codes); //i used return for calling recursive function.
    }else{
        var_dump($category_codes);
        return $category_codes;
    }
}
```